# file_get_contents() failed to open stream: No such file or directory php

Tags: php, upload, file-get-contents

With this script I should be able to upload three images from a form however I continue file_get_contents() failed to open stream: No such file or directory php I have added the full path etc.  Anyone have any ideas?

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    session_start();

    $full_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $folder = '/main_html/upload/';

    $upload_max_size = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
    $post_max_filesize = ini_get('post_max_filesize');

    // boundary  
    $time = md5(time());  
    $boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$time}x"; 
    $myfile = basename($_FILES['fileupload']['name']);
    $myfile2 = basename($_FILES['fileupload2']['name']);
    $myfile3 = basename($_FILES['fileupload3']['name']);

    //echo $myfile;
    $taille_maxi = 8000 * 1024;
    $taille = filesize($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name']);
    $taille2 = filesize($_FILES['fileupload2']['tmp_name']);
    $taille3 = filesize($_FILES['fileupload3']['tmp_name']);
    $extensions = array('.png', '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg');
    $extension = strrchr($_FILES['fileupload']['name'], '.');
    $extension2 = strrchr($_FILES['fileupload2']['name'], '.');
    $extension3 = strrchr($_FILES['fileupload3']['name'], '.');
    //Début des vérifications de sécurité...
    if (!isset($_FILES['fileupload']['name']) && !in_array($extension, $extensions))//Si l'extension n'est pas dans le tableau
    {
$erreur = 'file upload1 only file type png, gif, jpg, jpeg is accepted';
    }
    if (!isset($_FILES['fileupload2']['name']) && !in_array($extension2, $extensions))//Si l'extension n'est pas dans le tableau
    {
$erreur = 'only file type png, gif, jpg, jpeg is accepted';
    }
    if (!isset($_FILES['fileupload3']['name']) && !in_array($extension3,         $extensions))//Si l'extension n'est pas dans le tableau
    {
$erreur = 'only file type png, gif, jpg, jpeg is accepted';
    }
    if ($taille > $taille_maxi) {
$erreur = 'file upload 1: file size is too big ...';
    }
    if ($taille2 > $taille_maxi) {
$erreur = 'file upload 2: file size is too big ...';
    }
    if ($taille3 > $taille_maxi) {
$erreur = 'file upload 3: file size is too big ...';
    }
    if (!isset($erreur))//S'il n'y a pas d'erreur, on upload
    {
//On formate le nom du myfile ici...
$myfile = strtr($myfile, 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ', 'AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiioooooouuuuyy');
$myfile = preg_replace('/([^.a-z0-9]+)/i', '-', $myfile);

$myfile2 = strtr($myfile2, 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ', 'AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiioooooouuuuyy');
$myfile2 = preg_replace('/([^.a-z0-9]+)/i', '-', $myfile2);

$myfile3 = strtr($myfile3, 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ', 'AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiioooooouuuuyy');
$myfile3 = preg_replace('/([^.a-z0-9]+)/i', '-', $myfile3);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'], $full_path . $folder .         $myfile) || move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileupload2']['tmp_name'], $full_path . $folder . $myfile2) || move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileupload3']['tmp_name'], $full_path . $folder . $myfile3))  //Si la fonction renvoie TRUE, c'est que ça a fonctionné...
{

    $message = "Name: " . $_POST["name"] . "\nAddress: " . $_POST["address1"] . "\nCity: " . $_POST["city"] . "\nState: " . $_POST["state"] . "\nCountry: " . $_POST["country"];
    $message .= "\nZip : " . $_POST["zip"] . "\nHome Phone: " . $_POST["home_phone"] . "\nEmail: " . $_POST["email"];
    $message .= "\n\nEntry A Title: " . $_POST["entry_a_title"] . "\nEntry A Image Size: " . $_POST["entry_a_image_size"] . "\nEntry A Image Frame: " . $_POST["entry_a_image_frame"] . "\nEntry A Price: " . $_POST["entry_a_price"];
    $message .= "\nEntry A Filename: $myfile";
    $message .= "\n\nEntry B Title: " . $_POST["entry_b_title"] . "\nEntry B Image Size: " . $_POST["entry_b_image_size"] . "\nEntry B Image Frame: " . $_POST["entry_b_image_frame"] . "\nEntry B Price: " . $_POST["entry_b_price"];
    $message .= "\nEntry B Filename: $myfile2";
    $message .= "\n\nEntry C Title: " . $_POST["entry_c_title"] . "\nEntry C Image Size: " . $_POST["entry_c_image_size"] . "\nEntry C Image Frame: " . $_POST["entry_c_image_frame"] . "\nEntry C Price: " . $_POST["entry_c_price"];
    $message .= "\nEntry C Filename: $myfile3";
    $message .= "\n\nDelivery: " . $_POST["delivery"] . "\n ";
    $message .= "\nMembership Status: " . $_POST["Membership_status"] . "\nPayment Method: " . $_POST["Payment_Method"] . "\n\nDate: " . date("d/m/Y") . "\nTime: " . date('h:i:s A') . "\n ";

    $message .= "\n\nNOTE: If all images are not received please email";
    //$message .= "\n Form used = " . $_POST['formused'];
    //$message .= $tasktag;
    //$message .= "\n\nUploaded file 1: $myfile";
    //$message .= "\nUploaded file 1 location: $folder $myfile";
    //$message .= "\nUploaded file 2: $myfile2";
    //$message .= "\nUploaded file 2 location: $folder $myfile2";
    //$message .= "\nUploaded file 3: $myfile3";
    //$message .= "\nUploaded file 3 location: $folder $myfile3";

    //$message .= "\n\nPHP Max upload size: $upload_max_size";
    //$message .= "\n\nPHP Max post file size: $post_max_filesize";
    $message .= "\n\n$full_path";


    $boundary = "_" . md5(uniqid(rand()));

    $attached_file = file_get_contents($full_path . $folder . $myfile);
    //file name ie: ./image.jpg
    $attached_file = chunk_split(base64_encode($attached_file));

    $attached_file2 = file_get_contents($full_path . $folder . $myfile2);
    //file name ie: ./image.jpg
    $attached_file2 = chunk_split(base64_encode($attached_file2));

    $attached_file3 = file_get_contents($full_path . $folder . $myfile3);
    //file name ie: ./image.jpg
    $attached_file3 = chunk_split(base64_encode($attached_file3));

    //$attached = "\n\n". "--";

    if (file_get_contents($full_path . $folder . $myfile)) {
        $attached = "\n\n" . "--" . $boundary . "\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$myfile\"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$myfile\"\r\n\n" . $attached_file . "--" . $boundary . "--" . "\n\n";
        $headers = "From: " . $_POST["email"] . " \r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";

        $body = "--" . $boundary . "\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n\n" . $message . $attached;

        if ($_POST['subject'] == "National Show"){
            $email = 'email@gmail.com';
        }
        else {
            $email = 'email@gmail.com';
        }

        $subject = $_POST['name'] . " with Entry A";

        @mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers);

    }
    if (file_get_contents($full_path . $folder . $myfile2)) {
        $attached = "\n\n" . "--" . $boundary . "\nContent-Type: applicatio/octet-streamn; name=\"$myfile2\"\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$myfile2\"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\n" . $attached_file2 . "--" . $boundary . "--" . "\n\n";

        $headers = "From: " . $_POST["email"] . " \r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";

        $body = "--" . $boundary . "\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n\n" . $message . $attached;

        if ($_POST['subject'] == "National Show"){
            $email = 'email@gmail.com';
        }
        else {
            $email = 'email@gmail.com';
        }


        $subject = $_POST['name'] . " with Entry B";

        @mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    }
    if (file_get_contents($full_path . $folder . $myfile3)) {
        $attached = "\n\n" . "--" . $boundary . "\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$myfile3\"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$myfile3\"\r\n\n" . $attached_file3 . "--" . $boundary . "--" . "\n\n";

        $headers = "From: " . $_POST["email"] . " \r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";

        $body = "--" . $boundary . "\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n\n" . $message . $attached;

        if ($_POST['subject'] == "National Show"){
            $email = 'email@gmail.com';
        }
        else {
            $email = 'email@gmail.com';
        }


        $subject = $_POST['name'] . " with Entry C";

        // @mail($email,$subject,$body,$headers)

    }
if (@mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    if ($_POST['subject'] == "National Show")
        header('Location: http://www.example.org/app_2.htm');
    else
        header('Location: http://www.example.org/app_3.htm');
    //echo 'E-MAIL SEND WITH ATTACHMENT';

}
    //$attached .= "\n\n". "--" . $boundary . "--";

    //$attached .= "--" . "\n\n";

} else//Sinon (la fonction renvoie FALSE).
{
    echo 'UPLOAD ERROR !';
}
} else {
echo $erreur;
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the value for `$full_path . $folder . $myfile` and similar string concatenations?  Have you done4 any debugging to determine that these values are what you expect and that the files do indeed reside where you expect them to reside?

Comment: Try printing $full_path and see if it actually exists. If it does, try changing the permissions of the $full_path directory. chmod xxx dir

Comment: This is typically permissions (chmod) or user privileges (chown).

Comment: @MikeBrant it prints the complete path of doc root + path at htdocs + filename. Nu Gnoj Mik, Kohjah Breese the permissions on the upload directory are set to 755.

Comment: after some testing it seems that i cannot upload a file larger than 400KB even with both my upload_size and max_upload set to 20M

Comment: found the following php errors in my error log PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header informat and PHP Notice:  Undefined index: fileupload in /hermes/waloraweb061/b2688/moo.example/main_html/upload.php on line 21

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507